# Не работает array.prototype.filter()

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

```
const CONTACTS = [
    {
        name:"Luke",
        number:"+792132133",
        img:"https://media.giphy.com/media/l3fZZuwvELduur3sA/giphy.gif"
    },
    {
        name:"Han",
        number:"+278649348",
        img:"https://media.giphy.com/media/mWTM1IMLmUbp6/giphy.gif"
    },
    {
        name:"Leia",
        number:"+232335454",
        img:"https://media.giphy.com/media/9zcZ7lTMOHsY/giphy.gif"
    }
];

 const filter = document.getElementById("filter");
 CONTACTS.filter((el)=>
    {
        let searchValue = el.name.toLowerCase();
        return searchValue.indexOf(filter.value) != -1;
    });
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: в том. что filter **возвращает** отфильтрованную коллекцию

Comment: Ну,если что, я потом вывожу его,там всё та же коллекция.

Comment: а теперь посмотри на код и покажи куда ты присваиваешь результат фильтрации

Comment: @Grundy, а почему не ответом?

Comment: Ааа...хмм я думал,он и изменит в CONTACTS. Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @qwabra, я уверен, что уже были подобные вопросы. надо просто дубликат найти :)

Comment: @AlexPark, большинство методов у массива не меняют исходный массив, а просто возвращают новый. С ходу могу назвать только один метод. который работает _in-place_ - [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: @Grundy понял,спасибо